# Show/Hide tr elements based on multiple CSS classes and input from multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a large HTML page that contains a variety of tables. I would like to create a set of checkboxes at the top of the page that can be used to filter values in the various tables. A value in a `table` can belong to multiple groups, where a group is indicated by a unique CSS class. Here is the tricky part, when a group is selected, all values tagged with the corresponding CSS class must be shown. 
E.g. If Group A is selected all values tagged with class A should be displayed.

The following is a code snippet representing my display structure:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="A">
<input type="checkbox" name="B" value="B">

<tr id="abc" class="stylingClass A">
<tr id="def" class="stylingClass B">
<tr id="ghj" class="stylingClass A B">
```

I understand how to hide one `<tr>` element or another based on its checkbox, but I'm not sure how to get element `#ghj` to be displayed when only A is selected or only B is selected. Finally I would like this to be scalable to N groups. I know this is a tall order but I really I am quite stuck.

Comment: `jQuery's hasClass()` is a good way to start : https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $ins = $('input[type="checkbox"]'),
        $trs = $('tr.stylingClass');

    //change handler for checkboxes
    $ins.change(function () {
        //get the value of all checked checkboxes
        var vals = $ins.filter(':checked').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        //hide all trs
        $trs.hide();
        //if there is at least one checked item
        if (vals.length) {
            //show the trs with the any one of the selected value as class
            $trs.filter('.' + vals.join(', .')).show();
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vV57w/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation. This performs exactly as I need it to. I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var name = $(this).prop('name');
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
      $("tr." + name).show();
    else
      $("tr." + name).hide();
  });
});
```

*But after the page loading, all the  tags will be showed.*

I've just read that you want s be showed when only one checkbox is checked. I think about this...